# Prevent Autofill/Suggestion to overlay the keyboard

Tags: samsung, user-interface, text-input, auto-fill

When I tap into a text input, suggested entries are shown from top to bottom, which covers my entire letters-keyboard. This is annoying because I want to type in something.

[image]

Tapping again in the text input shrinks the dropdown to the desired height.

[image]

Is there a setting to force the second behavior to be the default behavior?

**EDIT**

I quick-fixed it by passing a random value to attribute `name`, so that the browser never finds associated values. But it's not a satisfying final solution.

**EDIT 2**

Reproducible on simple HTML form example https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

[image]

Samsung Keyboard is the chosen input method. This happens on Edge and Chrome. Tried Gboard, yes it also happens then. I don't know why some entries are remembered and new ones not. Somehow they are remembered.

Comment: Look into the App manifest of the app that you are using in the screenshot (the one that shows the dropdown). See if this attribute is present there, and if yes, what value it has. `android:windowSoftInputMode`. This might be a probable cause. Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: @Firelord Not sure what you mean with app manifest, I have a `manifest.json` in the root folder, but its React (JS library) specific and it does not contain anything with `android`. My application is a web application, not native.

Comment: @AndrewT. It is not coding/development question, the dropdown overlays the Keyboard from Android, from the Operating System. Its not the Web Content layer. I don't bother if the dropdown appears or not, it should just not overlay the Keyboard from the Operating system.

Comment: I just tried it on W3Schools and successfully reproduced the issue on Samsung Galaxy M12 and Pixel 3a.

Comment: I have experienced this issue multiple times recently in Chrome using Gboard on Galaxy S22 Ultra. However, I just tried repeating the issue but it is displaying properly now so either its been fixed and updated or is an intermittent issue so will update with screenshot if I experience it again.

Comment: Based on repeated tests, it's an intermittent issue on a specific condition, like due to the free space above/below the form element. It's a bit hard to replicate this consistently.