# How do you close an autofill popup one time without closing the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, chrome-for-android, browser, auto-fill, microsoft-edge

Goal is to use the keyboard without resorting to typing somewhere else and copy pasting, or disabling autofill.

For example, how to I type 5 when in this scenario.
[image: chase otp]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have a duplicate question about the same issue, but it's not yet completely solved: [Prevent Autofill/Suggestion to overlay the keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249088/44325)